# vb.net read string after certain character

Tags: vb.net

I have an listbox which has some random URLs + basic info, eg:

```
[search website] - http://www.google.com/
[games website]  - http://www.miniclip.com/
```

Each line is an item.

When I try to use this code, it crashes:

```
Private Sub doubleclickitem(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick
    Dim url As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    Process.Start(url)
End Sub
```

The error is `the first characters are unknown for Process.Start`.

How can I start the url? Someone told me I have to read the lines after the first " - ". Is this right? If so, how can I do so?

Comment: "it crashes," is very vague - it'd be better to provide the actual exception you're receiving, and the line where it's occurring, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
url = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf(" - ") + 3)
```

Comment: This will work, until you hit a situation where you want the list to display something and redirect somewhere else, for example, the list could state "search" and redirect off to Google, etc.

Comment: @user2366842 That depends on how the list is designed.

Comment: @user2366842 `LastIndexOf` gets the position of the last ` - ` character so that should not be a problem.

Comment: You're correct, i retracted my comment because I realized it.

Answer (score 0):

you should be assigning a value to each text item in the list, then retrieving the value, and feeding that to process.start, for example if you want process.start to open google, then it would be like so....(provided you assign a value of http://www.google.com to whatever the selected item is)

```
Process.Start(ListBox1.SelectedValue)
```

this is for c#, but the same ideals will still apply http://forums.asp.net/t/1199141.aspx/1

Comment: it's not exactly what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
YourTextBox.Text = YourString.Substring(0, YourString.Text.LastIndexOf(" - "))
```